# Statistical Significance Test for Non-Normal Data

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I'm doing scientific research on wastewater viral concentration methods. My goal is to determine the best method out of 3 methods used throughout literature and show that the results are statistically significant. Though I also want to compare these methods to no concentration, supernatant only and pellet only. So in total there are technically 6 methods that I want to compare.

I have completed multiple experiments and in total have six data groups (Neat, Supernatant, Pellet, Filter Column, Polyethylene Glycol and Absoprtion-Elution) for each experiment. The data are Ct values from real-time PCR for a range of different viruses (Adenovirus, Enterovirus, Norovirus GII, Rotavirus, Influenza A, Influenza A H3, RSV B, MS2 and Equine Herpes Virus). We also give our negative results a value of 50 as this is the cylce that real-time PCR stops at and we can not be sure whether they are truly negative or would have values greater than 50.

My goal is to determine which of the 6 methods is statistically better at concentrating the viruses as a whole. So compiling all these data values together from all the experiments. When compiled together some of the group have larger sample sizes than others.

The neat, supernatant and pellet groups have 63 values in their data sets and the filter column, polyethylene glycol and abosorption-elution have 21. When assessed with the Sharpio-Wilk calculation for normality each group receives a p-value less than 0.000001.

So my question is which methods do I use to assess statistical significance with this data?

Comment: "nonparametric" is a attribute of methods rather than of data. Do you just mean "non-normal"? Non-normal is *very* different from nonparametric, since (i) there are parametric procedures that don't assume normality and (ii) nonparametric methods may sensibly be used with normal data. Note further that failure to reject normality doesn't mean your data were drawn from a normal distribution; in many situations, with small samples you'd be unlikely to reject normality in cases where you certainly shouldn't assume it.

Comment: +1 The added information is helpful.  Among other things, it shows us your data are (right) *censored* at 50.  If there is much censoring at all actually occurring, then of course your data won't look Normal!  You need methods to handle censored data at all stages of your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding more about your analysis, I think you will want to be performing the Kruskal–Wallis test.  This is essentially a non-parametric one-way ANOVA.  You can learn more about the test by searching this site or by viewing additional information about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance).

I'm not sure how you are using the sign test since the sign test is only for examining 2 different populations and you have indicated you have 5.

Comment: Thank you for that, I've done some reading and that seems appropriate followed some post-hoc tests. There seems to be a lot of post-hoc methods to choose from though and I have no idea which one to use

Comment: Why don't you update your post here and tell us a little more about your research?  What is your intention?  What are you testing/hoping to find?  If you can give us some background and a few more details we might be able to guide you into the best method.  Also, it might be possible to transform your data to that parametric tests can be applied.  This will give your tests more power and will help you to detect differences if they exist.

Comment: Is the updated version any better?

Comment: This is very helpful, indeed.  As  @whuber, your data have some properties which mean it will not look normal, so traditional "normal" methods of analysis, will not work.  I should have time later today to post back and offer some suggestions.

Comment: I ended up doing a Kruskal-Wallis test if that's right what post-hoc procedures would be applicable?